# Ensure output document is complete

Tags: json, webmethods

I am using webMethods and have the following problem:

A JSON document is coming in to a flow-webservice (_post).

The JSON contains fields with "null" values. Example:

```
{ "firstName" : null, "lastName" : "Kaiser",...}
```

For these fields the options *"Required"* and *"Allow null"* are set to "true".

Publishing the document works fine - including validation:

```
pub.publish:publish
```

Retrieving the document from the taskengine via

```
pub.task.taskclient.searchTasks
```

leads to an output without all fields whose values were "null" when publishing. Activating the validation here also throws respective errors.

How can I instruct webMethods / the taskengine to return the full document (including even the fields with null values)?

Comment: Forget my answer entirely. I deleted it. I just did a test and broker does return null when you pass in a null value in the field. So it's really about the Task  Engine API "pub.task.taskclient.searchTasks" and I can't help you there as I have no experience with Task Engine as stated initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talked to a SAG senior consultant. This is the normal behavior...